# На старых сайтах перестали загружаться Google Fonts (Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, google-fonts

В браузере Google Chrome на некоторых старых сайтах перестали загружаться шрифты Google (после последних обновлений).

Получаю такое сообщение:

> "A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script,
>   https://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1&packages=corechart,
>   is invoked via document.write. This MAY be blocked by the browser in
>   this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If
>   blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent
>   console message.See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more
>   details."

Comment: А вопрос в чем? Как исправить сайт или как исправить Хром?

Comment: естественно вопрос в том как исправить сайт.

Comment: Пример сайта есть?

Comment: Скрипт вызывается через document.write - так написано в сообщении об ошибке.

Comment: http://www.veneciya.ru/

Comment: я не могу повлиять на то через что и как вызывает гугл свои шрифты...

Comment: Шрифты тут ни при чем, они как грузились, так и грузятся. Сообщение относится к модулю опроса. Как написано в сообщении об ошибке, это МОЖЕТ привести к чему-то, а может и не привести (вроде опрос работает).

Comment: да, я уже заметил. Однако шрифт почему-то все равно не отображается... Речь идет о шрифте в меню в котором почему то вместо roboto condensed - отображается roboto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась не в предупреждениях, которые выводил хром, а в самом шрифте. У меня не установлены шрифты Roboto и Roboto Condensed в системе, но видимо они есть у хрома...

Так как в самом css правиле у гугла при загрузке указано

> src: local('Roboto Condensed'), local('Roboto Condensed'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptsansnarrow/v7/UyYrYy3ltEffJV9QueSi4SppsHecKHw584ktcwPXSnc.woff2) format('woff2');

то в первую очередь берутся шрифты из системы. Почему при этом он заменяет roboto condensed на roboto - это великая тайна...

Замена шрифта на PT Sans Narrow решила проблему.